# Applying android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true to fix an error creates another error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

Last time I created a bundle everything worked smoothly, then after two weeks, I kept working on my React Native project, I haven't added new package. Simply not a single package that could mess with bundling internals, but somehow I cannot generate an `apk` due to following errors.

At my first bundling attempt received following error

```
  Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease FAILED
  D8: Program type already present: 
  android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
```

after some google search, found following solution, I placed in the gradle.properties

```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
```

After I apply this change, some other error is thrown

`Task :react-native-audio:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED`

`symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app`

it cannot load find ActivityCompat and ContextCompat.

If someone could show me how to fix this, I would really appreciate it.

By the way those missing symbols are not `react-native-audio` related because if I delete import statements from `react-native-audio` another package will throw the same error.

Comment: Are you use `react-native-device-info` ?

Comment: @hongdevelop no I don't use that package

Comment: remove task folder `rm -rf /home/myid/Desktop/MyApp/.gradle/2.10/tasks/`

Comment: @hongdevelop I couldn't find tasks folder, but removed all of the (in my case) 4.10.2 then cleaned and recompiled but same INotificationSideChannel... error

Comment: One thing I'm trying to say is that you change the settings and the solution to the error 'Task :react-native-audio:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED'.